# WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn dynamic binding of Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I have a datagrid to which I set item source `List<User>`.
One of the properties of User is `Department` which is Enum with descriptions.

In the datagrid Departments are displayed as combobox for a user to select one.
I need to bind enum value and description to the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`.

So far I managed either to bind Enum to `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource` thus it works but the description isn't taken into account.
Or set collection of Value, Description to `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource` and set `DisplayMemberPath`, `SelectedValuePath`. But in this case the value doesn't bind to DataGridComboBoxColumn.

The View:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="userData" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,157,10,80" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
 AutoGeneratingColumn="UserData_OnAutoGeneratingColumn" DisplayMemberPath="Description"/>
```

The Code:

```
    private void UserData_OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.SortMemberPath == "Department")
        {
            (e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn).ItemsSource = EnumExtension.ProvideValue();

            (e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn).DisplayMemberPath = "Description";
            (e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn).SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("Value");
            (e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn).SelectedValuePath = "Value";
        }
    }
```

Enum extension:

```
public static class EnumExtension
{
    public static List<ValueDescriptionVm<Departments>> ProvideValue()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(Departments))
        .Cast<object>()
        .Select(enumValue => new ValueDescriptionVm<Departments>()
        {
            Value = (Departments)enumValue,
            Description = GetDescription((Enum)enumValue)
        }).ToList();
    }

    private static string GetDescription(Enum enumValue)
    {
        FieldInfo fi = enumValue.GetType().GetField(enumValue.ToString());
        var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

        if (attributes.Length > 0)
        {
            return attributes[0].Description;
        }

        return enumValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have asked a similar question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45349465/wpf-datagrid-datagridcomboboxcolumn-cells-displayed-value)  , hope it helps

Comment: @stuicidle What is ComboBoxSelectedItem in .SelectedValueBinding = ComboBoxSelectedItem? (A collection of Description, Value)?

Comment: In the example it is a ComboBoxOption object, that gets updated when you make a selection from the combo box

Comment: I have updated my post, hopefully it will make a little more sense if you are still have difficulty's :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path of the `SelectedValueBinding` should be the name of the property of the `User` class:

```
(e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn).SelectedValueBinding = new Binding("Department");
```

Then the binding should work provided that the type of the `Department` property of the `User` class and the `Value` property of the `ValueDescriptionVm<Departments>` class is the same.